# Need an explanation about a slow query with MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query-optimization

I have a "simple" query how takes 0.7678 seconds or more to be executed with MariaDB.

Here is the query:

```
select  `referenceNumber`
    from  `invoice`
    where  `groupId` = 3550
      and  `referenceNumber` >= 301
    order by  `referenceNumber` desc
    limit  1;
```

These columns have an index: "referenceNumber", "groupId"

Here is the result of an `EXPLAIN`:
[image]

I found a solution by creating a subquery like that:

```
select  `referenceNumber`
    from  (
        SELECT  id
            from  `invoice`
            where  `groupId` = 3550
              and  `referenceNumber` >= 301
          ) as subquery
    JOIN  invoice as invoice  ON invoice.id = subquery.id
    order by  `referenceNumber` desc
    limit  1;
```

This query takes like 0.0011 seconds.

Here is the result of an EXPLAIN:
[image]

Do you have an explanation about the poor performance of the first query?

Two surprising findings:

The query without the `` where `groupId` = 3550 `` takes only 0.0005 seconds like that:

```
select  `referenceNumber`
    from  `invoice`
    where  `referenceNumber` >= 301
    order by  `referenceNumber` desc
    limit  1;
```

The query without the `` order by `referenceNumber` desc `` takes only 0.0011 seconds like that:

```
select  `referenceNumber`
    from  `invoice`
    where  `groupId` = 3550
      and  `referenceNumber` >= 301
    limit  1;
```

Here is the schema of this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `invoice` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `groupId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `referenceNumber` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
            COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `invoice`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `invoice_groupid_index` (`groupId`),
  ADD KEY `invoice_referencenumber_index` (`referenceNumber`);

ALTER TABLE `invoice`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;
```

Thank you really much for your help!

Comment: It helps a lot if you paste in the results as *plain text* instead of smudgy little screenshots, especially ones with truncation.

Comment: Have you ever tuned your server? Some people run stock configurations that are absolutely starved for memory.

Comment: You also need an index on `groupId, referenceNumber` for the type of query you're doing. Having the `groupId` index only gets you so far, the rest of the rows have to be matched with a scan.

Comment: Thank you @tadman I will try to improve the results in plain text.
I tested this query in local with Docker but also on a shared hosting server. The result is poor in this two environnements.

Comment: If there's one thing to learn first about server performance it's that `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is *absolutely* critical. If it's set too small, you're sacrificing a ton of performance for no reason.

Comment: @tadman you have completely right!! I created an index with `groupId, referenceNumber` and now the first query takes only 0.0005 seconds. Amazing, thank you really much!!

Comment: Can you explain me why in this case we need to have this common index?

Comment: @tadman - (re: starving) Newer versions of MySQL (5.7+?) set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` based on RAM size.  That setting is _not_ relevant for this trivial query.

Comment: @RickJames I can never be sure if this is on a highly-loaded production database, or on someone's relatively overpowered developer machine. I've just seen instances of where changing that parameter improved performance by several orders of magnitude since the default was something pathetic like 128MB of memory. If that default has *finally* changed, that's great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to indexes, having an index on column A and column B will not help if there's a query involving both of them.

Adding an index on A creates a look-up table to records with various A values, and can provide support for `ORDER`, `BETWEEN` and other operations involving ordered values. Importantly it *does not* account for the order of anything B related.

Likewise, an index on B does much the same thing, ignoring the order of A.

In general, if you want to query `WHERE A=? ORDER BY B` then you need an index on `A,B`. This creates an index with data sorted on A, then sub-sorted (for equal values of A) on B. This makes comparisons very quick, they can often happen entirely within the index.

Comment: Thank you really much for your detailed explanation.

I followed your suggestion and added an index on `A,B`. The request is really fast now.

You solved my problem in 2 minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

- The subqueries are overkill.  They may involve building a temp table, which adds cost.  (There are other situations where this is actually optimal, but not here.)
- The `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` gives you a random item; don't do it that way.  This is, in my opinion, not valid, so it does not matter how fast it is.
- For performance, the rest need you to replace `KEY(groupId)` with

  ```
    INDEX(groupId, referenceNumber)  -- in this order
  ```
- Some of your formulations lead the optimizer into a quandary of whether to use `KEY(groupId)` or `KEY(referenceNumber)`.  Each has its pros and cons.  But the Optimizer does not have adequate information to choose between them.  The composite index above will home in on the single row that is desired.
- Note:  My suggested index is both "composite" and "covering".  See those terms for further reference.